# x86 Assembly, How to get a user input wihout it being displayed in console?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I'm really new to assembly language and trying to write a simple program. It gets a user input (password) which should not be shown in console.

For normal input, I use the Irvine32 library like so. But this method displays the input user enters, for inputs like password, this should be hidden which I'm not sure how to do.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
idPromptStr byte "Please enter ID : ", 13, 10, 0
id DWORD ? 
.code
main proc
    mov edx,OFFSET idPromptStr
    call    WriteString
    call ReadInt ;Reads the integer value from console and moves it to eax.
    mov id,eax ;Input value is taken in eax. 
main endp
end main
```

Comment: You need to use `GetConsoleMode`, clear bit 2 and then `SetConsoleMode`. I've already a working example. I'll post an answer later if nobody did meanwhile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** You need to clear the `ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT` bit from the console mode, using [`GetConsoleMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolemode) and [`SetConsoleMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode).

`ReadString` uses `ReadConsoleA` internally, using the console that Windows automatically creates for executable with the console subsystem (i.e. it uses `GetStdHandle` to retrieve the console input and output handles).

[image: Internal code of ReadString]

Whenever `ReadConsoleA` will or will not echo the read characters depends on the *console mode*.
Specifically, the flag `ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT` (value 0x4), when cleared, will prevent echoing the characters.

To get the current console mode use `GetConsoleMode`, to clear the `ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT` bit AND the mode with the negation of `ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT` (i.e. `and rm32, ~ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT` in NASM).
Then set the console mode with this new value.
Here's the function to disable and reenable the echo:

```
  ;No args, return the console mode to pass to EnableEcho
DisableEcho:
  push esi 
  push edi 
  
  ;-- Get console input handle ---
  push STD_INPUT_HANDLE
  call _GetStdHandle@4
  
  mov esi, eax   
  
  
  ;-- Clear the ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT bit --
  sub esp, 04
  push esp 
  push eax
  call _GetConsoleMode@8
  pop eax
  mov edi, eax 
  
  and eax, ~ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT
 
  push eax 
  push esi
  call _SetConsoleMode@8
  
  mov eax, edi

  pop edi 
  pop esi  
  ret

  ;edx = value returned from DisableEcho
EnableEcho:
  ;-- Get console input handle ---
  push STD_INPUT_HANDLE
  call _GetStdHandle@4
  
  ;-- Set mode --
  push edx 
  push eax 
  call _SetConsoleMode@8
    
  ret
```

**Note** this code is written for **NASM** and to be linked with Microsoft's **link**. Adapt it to your tools.

`DisableEcho` returns the original console mode that you must pass to `EnableEcho` (in `edx` as per Irvine's call convention).
Like:

```
call DisableEcho

;Here echo is disabled when calling ReadXXX

mov edx, eax              ;Assuming eax has been preserved
call EnableEcho
```

Adapt the code to your needs, I didn't use global variables because, contrary to Irvine, I prefer pure functions whenever possible.
Some people find the lack of global variables harder to follow.

Here's a complete program that will read a username, a password, and an OTP code (just to show that echo is enabled *before* and *after* the password prompt) and then will print all of them.

```
BITS 32

GLOBAL _start

%define STD_INPUT_HANDLE -10
%define ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT 4

%define STRLEN 82

EXTERN _ReadString@0
EXTERN _ExitProcess@4
EXTERN _SetConsoleMode@8
EXTERN _GetConsoleMode@8
EXTERN _GetStdHandle@4
EXTERN _WriteString@0

SECTION .bss

  myUsername    resb STRLEN
  myPassword    resb STRLEN
  myOTP         resb STRLEN 
 
SECTION .data

  strUsername   db "Username: ", 0
  strPassword   db "Password:", 0
  strOTP        db 13, 10, "OTP code: ", 0   
  strCRLF       db 13, 10, 0
  
SECTION .text

_start:

  ;-- Read the username --

  mov edx, strUsername
  call _WriteString@0

  mov edx, myUsername
  mov ecx, STRLEN 
  call _ReadString@0

  ;-- Disable echo --
  call DisableEcho
  mov esi, eax 
  
  ;-- Read the password --

  mov edx, strPassword
  call _WriteString@0

  mov edx, myPassword 
  mov ecx, STRLEN 
  call _ReadString@0
  
  ;-- Restore the echo ---
  
  mov edx, esi 
  call EnableEcho

  ;-- Read the otp --

  mov edx, strOTP
  call _WriteString@0

  mov edx, myOTP
  mov ecx, STRLEN 
  call _ReadString@0
  
  ;-- Show --
  
  
  mov edx, myUsername
  call _WriteString@0

  mov edx, strCRLF
  call _WriteString@0
  
  mov edx, myPassword
  call _WriteString@0
  
  mov edx, strCRLF
  call _WriteString@0
  
  mov edx, myOTP
  call _WriteString@0
  
  ;-- Exit --
  
  push 0
  call _ExitProcess@4
  
  
  ;No args, return the console mode to pass to EnableEcho
DisableEcho:
  push esi 
  push edi 
  
  ;-- Get console input handle ---
  push STD_INPUT_HANDLE
  call _GetStdHandle@4
  
  mov esi, eax   
  
  
  ;-- Clear the ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT bit --
  sub esp, 04
  push esp 
  push eax
  call _GetConsoleMode@8
  pop eax
  mov edi, eax 
  
  and eax, ~ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT
 
  push eax 
  push esi
  call _SetConsoleMode@8
  
  mov eax, edi

  pop edi 
  pop esi  
  ret

  ;edx = value returned from DisableEcho
EnableEcho:
  ;-- Get console input handle ---
  push STD_INPUT_HANDLE
  call _GetStdHandle@4
  
  ;-- Set mode --
  push edx 
  push eax 
  call _SetConsoleMode@8
    
  ret
```